# PHP / regular expression to check if a string contains a word of a certain length

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to check whether a received string contains any words that are more than 20 characters in length. For example the input string :

hi there asssssssssssssssssssskkkkkkkk how are you doing ?

would return true.

could somebody please help me out with a regexp to check for this. i'm using php.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `"100000000000000000000000000000 leagues under the sea"` a match? What does the word "word" mean to you?

Comment: no that would not pass the filter. a word for me is an english word, no numbers. the text i'm checking is profile text for a dating site.

Answer (score 5):

```
/\w{20}/
```

...filller for 15 characters....

Answer (score 4):

You can test if the string contains a match of the following pattern:

```
[A-Za-z]{20}
```

The construct `[A-Za-z]` creates a character class that matches ASCII uppercase and lowercase letters. The `{20}` is a finite repetition syntax. It's enough to check if there's a match that contains 20 letters, because if there's a word that contains more, it contains at least 20.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Finite Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

---

#### PHP snippet

Here's an example usage:

```
$strings = array(
  "hey what the (@#$&*!@^#*&^@!#*^@#*@#*&^@!*#!",
  "now this one is just waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay too long",
  "12345678901234567890123 that's not a word, is it???",
  "LOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOL that's just unacceptable!",
  "one-two-three-four-five-six-seven-eight-nine-ten",
  "goaaaa...............aaaaaaaaaalll!!!!!!!!!!!!!!",
  "there is absolutely nothing here"
);

foreach ($strings as $str) {
  echo $str."\n".preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]{20}/', $str)."\n";
}
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/sPM4D)):

```
hey what the (@#$&*!@^#*&^@!#*^@#*@#*&^@!*#!
0
now this one is just waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay too long
1
12345678901234567890123 that's not a word, is it???
0
LOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOLOL that's just unacceptable!
1
one-two-three-four-five-six-seven-eight-nine-ten
0
goaaaa...............aaaaaaaaaalll!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
0
there is absolutely nothing here
0
```

As specified in the pattern, `preg_match` is true when there's a "word" (as defined by a sequence of letters) that is at least 20 characters long.

If this definition of a "word" is not adequate, then simply change the pattern to, e.g. `\S{20}`. That is, any seqeuence of 20 non-whitespace characters; now all but the last string is a match ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/gjeP7)).

Answer (score -2):

I think the [strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function is what you looking for. you can do something like this:

```
if (strlen($input) > 20) {
    echo "input is more than 20 characters";
}
```

Comment: That will read the entire string and return the length, not individual words within the string.